# Ядро торрент трекера

Tags: torrent

Давно ищу. Видимо плохо.
Может кто подскажет.
Мне не нужно внешнее оформление, статистика, регистрация и прочая муть.
Необходимо самому заливать торрент на свой же сервак, после чего размещать ссылку на его скачивание. Больше ничего.
Существует ли такое чудо?

з.ы.
Анонсер типа OpenTracker не катит

Answer (score 1):

Вот, [две](http://habrahabr.ru/post/127879/) [статьи](http://habrahabr.ru/post/128117/). Вас это интересует ? Если нет, поищите сами на хабре, там еще несколько статей должно быть похожих на ваш вопрос если не ошибаюсь.

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понимаю, анонсер вам не нужен.
Для работы с торент файлами вы можете использовать класс [torrent-rw](https://github.com/adriengibrat/torrent-rw/blob/master/Torrent.php)
Он позволит вам разбирать файлы на лету и хранить информацию в БД ну или готовить сразу же файлы на раздачу.

Comment: Походу дела то что нужно. Сейчас буду ковыряться. Спасибо.